# How to treat a multi-level continuous variable?

Tags: covariance, glmm, predictor

I'm not sure what type of covariate I'm dealing with and how to treat it in a glmm.

I have many 1600-ha blocks. Within each block, I'm interested in the variable Burn Severity. There are 4 possible attributes of Burn Severity: unburned, low, medium, and high. Within each attribute, values can range from 0-1600 ha, and necessarily add up to 1600 ha.

If I treat each attribute as an individual continuous covariate (4 continuous covariates with area as the value), they are unsurprisingly correlated (specifically, Low + Med, Low + Unburn, and Med + Unburn are correlated).

I think I should possibly treat Burn Severity as a single dummy variable? But I do want to retain the area values, and am not sure how. I'm lacking the proper terms to describe this type of covariate in order to do further reading. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So does each block contain 1,600 pixels (for lack of a better term), each of which gets labeled as unburned, low, medium, or high? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ulfelder I suppose you could think of it that way....I think it's better to just think of it as area; 1600 hectares total, with for example 1000 ha unburned, 200 ha low burn, 200 moderate burn, and 200 highly burned

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is really a single, scalar variable, not four separate variables and not categorical.

My inclination would be to assign weights to the levels that reflect your sense of their relative severity and then use those in an equation you use to compute a single score. So, for example, you could assign weights of 0, 1, 2, and 3, respectively, if you think the three levels are proportionate that way and then compute burn severity as `0(unburned) + 1(low) + 2(moderate) + 3(high)`.

I would use domain expertise to set the weights, but you might then rescale the results before modeling for the usual reasons.